# Download file in an authenticated state with wget in bash

Tags: bash, authentication, wget

I'm trying to download the Civit AI model [Realities Edge XL Turbo](https://civitai.com/models/129666/realities-edge-xl-lcmsdxlturbo) in a shell, but since the author has required the users to be logged in to download it, I am having trouble to use wget inside my runpod shell. Looking into the cookies of civit ai, I could find a __Secure-civitai-token which I tried to insert into the wget command with wget `--header="Authorization: Bearer JWT_TOKEN" modelurl` but this still does not work. Does anyone know how I can download this model inside a shell?

Comment: `wget --keep-session-cookies --http-user=USER --http-password=PASS`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get it to work with wget, but that information given by https://education.civitai.com/civitais-guide-to-downloading-via-api/ is about using it with curl, not wget.

For example to get the model from https://civitai.com/models/308337/aetherverse-xl, you need to first the the download link (which is NOT the model page url!) by right clicking on the download button and then choosing "copy link", from which you get https://civitai.com/api/download/models/346065.

So the full command line for getting the model is

> curl -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer
> **your-civitai-api-key**" https://civitai.com/api/download/models/346065
> --output=aetherverseXL_v10.safetensors

Ok, I've just figure out how to do it using wget:

> wget "civitai.com/api/download/models/346065?token=apikey"
> --content-disposition

Note the use of --content-disposition so that wget will save the model with the correct filename.